# Can we Send data from nested child component to ancestor Parent component using useContext()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm sharing code here but I'm getting an error

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'userAge' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.

Child component:

```
import React, { useContext, createContext, useState } from "react";
export const AgeIs = createContext();
export default function Childc() {
const [age, setAge] = useState("24");
return(
<AgeIs.Provider value={{ userAge: [age, setAge] }}>
    <ParentComp />
  </AgeIs.Provider>
)}
```

Sending age to parent component:

```
import { AgeIs } from "./Childc";
const { userAge } = useContext(AgeIs);
export default function ParentComp() {
const [age, setAge] = userAge;
return (
<div>
    <h1>{age}</h1>
  </div>
)}
```

If `useContext` doesnt cater this problem please suggest a solution for this kind of problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`useContext` should be used inside the component.

Something like this should work:

```js
function ParentComp() {
  const { userAge } = useContext(AgeIs);
  const [age, setAge] = userAge;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{age}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setAge((age) => age + 1)}>Increase Age</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### More in depth explanation

`useContext`, `useState` and others are all hooks. This define a local state for a component. If you use it outside of the component then it will be called only when the file is imported, meaning that

1. the Context was not defined when you requested it for the first time
2. the Context will not update whenever the component is updated or
   created for the first time

You can read more about how hooks work in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html)